# How to link containers in docker?

Tags: docker

Here's the result when I type `docker ps` :
[image: here is the image when i type docker ps]

I have 3 docker containers: webapps, redis and rabbitmq. I want to link container webapps to container redis and rabbitmq container. In non docker apps, mywebapps can send message to rabbitmq and write/read redis.

I tried using command like this

```
docker run --name rabbitmq -p 8080:80 --link webapps:nimmis/apache-php7 -d rabbitmq
```

but it does not work.

Here is my config.php on webapps where I am trying to send messages via rabbitmq:

```
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 5672);
```

I tried to change localhost with hostname

```
define('HOST', 'rabbitmq');
define('PORT', 5672);
```

Error message says `connection refused`.

It seems that in my three containers needs to be configured in the same network namespace.

Comment: I am also kind of new to Docker but I am almost certain that using `-p` along with `--link` is nothing but useless. `-p 8080:80` will tell the docker proxy to make the port 8080 in your container exposed to the port 80 on your system. So if you type `-p 6379:6379` as well for your redis container, your php app can use redis just by connecting to `localhost:6379`.

Answer (score 150):

**[Linking is a legacy feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)**. Please use [user defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user-defined-network):

```
docker network create mynetwork
```

Then rerun your containers using this network:

```
docker run --name rabbitmq -p 8080:80 -d --network mynetwork rabbitmq
```

Do the same for other containers that you want connected with each other.

Using "user defined networks", you have an "internal name resolution" at your disposal (somewhat like domain name resolution when visiting websites). You can use the names of the container that you want to refer to, in order to resolve the IP addresses of containers, as long as they are running on the same "user defined network". With this, you can resolve the IP address of the `rabbitmq` container with its name, within other containers, on the same network.

*All* containters on the same "user defined network" will have network connectivity. There is no need for "legacy linking".

Comment: "You can use the names of the container that you want to refer to, in order to resolve the IP addresses of containers, as long as they are running on the same "user defined network"." - Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Just a side note, if you do the port mapping like above, 8080 is the host port, 80 is the docker container port. Accessing docker container from another docker container requires the docker container port, namely 80, instead of 8080.

Comment: By default, all docker containers in the same host are already connected via a default bridge network right ? So, even if a custom network is not defined, won't the communication happen? Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 27):

For inter-container dependencies and links, you'll want to use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) where you can define the [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/links) between containers.

In your root directory where you store your Docker files, just make a new file called `docker-compose.yml` and here you can define your containers as services which rely on each other like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapps:
    build: .
    links:
      - "rabbitmq:rabmq"
      - "redis"

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq

  redis:
    image: redis
```

so here in the definition of the `webapps` service, you see it `links` the other two services `rabbitmq` and `redis`. What this means is that when the `webapps` container is build, an entry to it's `hosts` file is made such that the domain name `redis` is translated to the IP and port number of the actual container.

You have the option to change the name of how this container is address by using the `service:alias` notation, like how I defined the `rabbitmq` to 
use the alias `rabmq` inside the container `webapps`.

To now build and start your containers using `docker-compose` just type:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

So connecting to another container is as simple as using this alias as the name of the host.

Since you are using `docker-compose` in this case, it creates a docker network automatically to connect all the containers so you shouldn't have to worry about that. But for more information have a look at the docs: 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/specifying-custom-networks

Answer (score 10):

You need to link rabbitmq and redis to your webapps container and not the other way arround.

```
    #run redis container
    docker run --name some-redis -d redis

    #run rabbitmq container
    docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq

    #run webapps container
    docker run --name webapps -p 8080:80 --link some-redis:redis --link some-rabbit:rabbitmq nimmis/apache-php7
```

First run redis and rabbitmq containers. 
Then run webapps container with links to the 2 containers.

Now, to configure redis host in the webapps - its easy. You can simply use env variable **'REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR'**. Because once a container is linked you get its env variables. and redis exports that variable.

Regarding the rabbitmq host - you can get the ip after the rabbit container is up by:

```
    RABBITMQ_IP=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' some-rabbit)
```

and then pass it in --env when you run the webapps container.

Comment: oke thanks..problem solved... iin file config, i change local ip address of my rabbitmq server from localhost to ipaddress

to see ip address... i type 

docker inspect [containerid]


thanks Nesia Amit , Farhad Farahi and Pit 
:)

Answer (score 5):

In my experience working with declaratives such as docker-compose.yml is okay, but simply  you can use

```
docker run -d -P  -link  nimmis/apache-php7  rabbitmq redis
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your services to use a user-defined network in your `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:

  webapps:
    image: nimmis/apache-php7
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    networks:
      - my-network

  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: overlay
```

Then do:

```
docker swarm init
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml my-stack
```

Check out the full example at https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/

Answer (score 0):

You could access the IP Address of your Redis Container.

Start `rabbitmq` and get the internal IP Adress:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' rabbitmq > .rabbitmq.ip
```

Now, you can add an Apache configuration and add the internal IP Address for rabbitmq while starting the `webapps` container. Or simply add an entry in the Apache container's /etc/hosts like:

```
// the dynamic internal IP of rabbitmq is known once rabbitmq starts:
172.30.20.10 rabbitmq.redis.local
```