# Connection refused while trying to connect one docker container from another

Tags: docker, connection, docker-compose, containers, docker-run

My question can be naive, but I'm new to development and docker, and couldn't figure out the solution.
I have an image of GraphDB-Free which I can run as a docker container, and it runs on localhost:7200. I can access it in chrome also.

Now I have another module ModelService which is spring boot application to read and write data to the GraphDB. I created an image of the module and ran it as a docker container, but everytime it gives me a Connection Refused error like the following:

`Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:7200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)`.

This problem is only If I run the module ModelService by using a docker container. If I run it as a simple java application from intelliJ, it runs fine and gets connected with GraphDB instance that I ran inside a container.

This ModelService module starts a springboot application and has a `application.properties` file that specifies it to connect with GraphDB using `register.graphDbUrl=http://localhost:7200` and `register.repositoryId=SYSTEM`.

I believe I'm missing something with Docker containers. I don't want to use Docker-Compose, and point is to run both containers as stand alone containers. I have tried `--link` while running docker run but it doesn't helps.

I run the GDB instance using `docker run -p 7200:7200 graphDB-image`, and ModelService using `docker run -p 9001:8080 modelService-image`. I do wait before the GraphDB is completey up and running, and then I run other container.

Can somebody help in this. I've struggling with it for 2 days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to link container in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768157/how-to-link-container-in-docker)

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for unfortunately. :( My ModelService application is a springboot application which while launching the Tomcat, tries to connect with localhost:7200, and crashes there.

Comment: So you are trying to connect from one container to another? If you use localhost inside a container, it does not point to the localhost of the *host* machine, but to the localhost of the container, which is not the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach this might also solve your problem (using host network).

Comment: @TeemuRisikko This is the problem yes, to access localhost from inside the other container (other container will fail to run, which is a springboot app, if localhost is nor reachable). I have seen the post you have mentioned, but couldn't get the solution for my case. It might be that I'm a bit new to these concepts and need a bit more simple clarification. Hopefully someone can help, thinking that I'm a complete beginner.