# Failed to access MongoDB in container through Flask application

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, mongoengine

So guys n gals, hope you can help me.

So i'm diving into docker containers right now and i try to port my application (flask+mongodb) into two seperate containers. MongoDB container is set up and works great, running a mongoexpress container with a link gives me the access to the database i wished. Now i ported my Flask application and the login page loads fine (so the docker port itself works) but even though i run the container with a link to my database container, i get a server error when i try to load content from the database.

The logs give me the following traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py", line 37, in __get__
    queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 190, in _get_collection
    db = cls._get_db()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 179, in _get_db
    return get_db(cls._meta.get('db_alias', DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 241, in get_db
    db = conn[conn_settings['name']]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1323, in __getitem__
    return database.Database(self, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 107, in __init__
    "of %s" % (string_type.__name__,))
TypeError: name must be an instance of str
```

So my Flask-MongoEngine is set up like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGODB_DB"] = 'database-name'
db = MongoEngine(app)
```

Basically my database should be available on localhost at the standard port 27017. Is there anything i have to consider when connecting with Flask to the container or should the link not already expose the ports as expected?mongoexpress works and has access, so it has to be a problem with my setup.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the below answer. Can you post the config info in your flask app?

Comment: @RobertMoskal I actually don't know what the config info is. Where can i find it?

Comment: The WSGI options are unchanged from this image https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to link container in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768157/how-to-link-container-in-docker) I think you just need to follow the instructions in there.  Or better still use docker-compose

Comment: @RobertMoskal User defined networks are the way to go! Solved my problem outside of the suggestions. As it seems, my configuration for Flask was simply not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end things were simpler than i thought. As i migrated my code from Apache2 to Nginx, the flow of my code changed without me noticing it. So my configuration lines for Flask were simply not called.

Answer (score 0):

At least put this in your settings:

```
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'mongo'
```

The raison why your mongoexpress works is it looks for mongo on host named `mongo` by default, so when you do `docker run -it --rm -p 8081:8081 --link YOUR_MONGODB_CONTAINER:mongo mongo-express` it can find the linked mongo instance. However in flask-mongoengine, the host is default to localhost.

Comment: Good Idea! My host in mongoexpress seems to be "e63206b1b9b9" but that does also not work for my flask application.

Comment: can you try this `app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://mongo:27017/database-name"` and remove `app.config["MONGODB_*`

Comment: Unsuccessful. So through shell i can access mongod processes on localhost and "e63206b1b9b9". mongo does not work.

Comment: what do you mean access mongod process through shell? mongo does not work?

Comment: "mongo --host localhost" and "mongo --host e63206b1b9b9" do work to connect me to the mongo shell (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/). "mongo --host mongo" does not work.

Comment: where did you run these? on the host I suppose? try `mongo --host mongo` inside the container

Comment: i'm running the container with the bash keyword. As i said, --host mongo does not work. Thank you i solved my problem.