# How to run Database services in Docker container?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, redis

Trying to build an docker image to install Node and databases in image.
Databases are installed but services are not running while trying to go for container logs ..

```
FROM ubuntu:lastest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget gnupg && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv D68FA50FEA312927 && \
    echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs mongodb-org redis-server && \
    node -v && \
    npm -v
```

Please do help regarding this issue, i am new to Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually start mongod, e.g. like

```
apt-get install -y nodejs mongodb-org redis-server && \
mongod --fork && \
node -v && \
npm -v
```

But bear in mind that mongo should be configured first and it requires some time to spin up.

As a side note it is considered a better practice to compose individual single-purpose docker images rather than pack both database and application in a single image.
Please read https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Answer (score 2):

Best run the database containers separate, e.g. one container for [mongodb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) and one for [redis](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis). Then connect your application container to those containers (either by [links (deprecated)](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) or by creating and sharing a network [as discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768466/7095540). You also do not to have to start from `ubuntu:latest`, but can start with a node image like [nodejs](https://hub.docker.com/_/node). Some 'orchestration', like `docker-compose`, can make a task of plugging these services together much easier, see [this tutorial](https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-compose-for-nodejs-development/) (the postgres database in the article can easily be exchanged by mongodb and redis). Also consider reading the [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) for Dockerfile writing.