# Sharing a created directory within a Docker container to another Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Massive Docker noob here in dire need of help. There are two docker containers: `simple-jar` and `elk`. `simple-jar` produces log files in `/logs` directory within its container, and another application, `elk`, needs to access these log files to do some processing on them.

1. How can I share the `/logs` directory so that `elk` docker container can access it?

This is the Dockerfile for `simple-jar`:

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY target/pulsar_logging_consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/src/pulsar_logging_consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
EXPOSE 6650
CMD java -jar /usr/src/pulsar_logging_consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elk:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  simple-jar:
    build:
      context: pulsar_logging_consumer/
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./pulsar_logging_consumer/logs
        target: /usr/share/logs
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "6500:6500"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options,

**1.** Create an external named volume, this needs to be created by you (the user) otherwise fails, using the following command

```
docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=none \
--opt device=/var/opt/my_data_logs \
--opt o=bind logs_data
```

> Select the volume type that fits, there are different types like nfs, ext3 and 3rd party plugins.

In your docker-compose.yml file

version '3'

```
volumes:
  logs_data:
    external: true

services:
  app:
    image: yourimage:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - logs_data:/your/path
```

2. Share volumes: Start a container using volumes defined by another, (top-level volumes)

   version '3'

   ```
    volumes:
      logs_data:
        external: true

    services:
      app1:
        image: appimage:latest
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - logs_data:/your/path:ro
      app2:
        image: yourimage:latest
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        volumes:
          - logs_data:/your/path:ro
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using `--link` See [how to link container in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768157/how-to-link-container-in-docker)

An better way is to use volumes https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Links never had anything to do with filesystem sharing.  They're obsolete in modern Docker.  This answer would be more informative if it included a description of how to use volumes to address the problem in the question, more than just a link to the Docker documentation.